# How to set the state from a button inside static navigationoption react-native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I want to click the TouchableOpacity and set the state true so that  will open. I am getting error. and how to align the button in center at the header? alignSelf is not working.

`

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {
  StyleSheet,
  SafeAreaView,
  View,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Text,
} from 'react-native';
import Menu from '../../src/components/menubar';

export default class SearchPage extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {isMenubarDisplayed: false};
  }

  static navigationOptions = {
    headerTitle: () => {
      return (
        <TouchableOpacity
             onPress={()=> this.setState({isMenubarDisplayed: true})}>
            <Icon name="search" size={20} color="#000" />
        </TouchableOpacity>
      );
    },
    headerTitleStyle: {
      alignSelf: 'center',
      flex: 1,
    },
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>

        {this.state.isMenubarDisplayed ? (
          <Menu />
        ) : null}

      </SafeAreaView>
    );
  }
}`
```

Comment: can you share your code in expo?

Comment: @VahidAkhtar https://snack.expo.io/@supu/bda6d8

Comment: what are you trying to do in menu and can you share your requirement?

Comment: I want to click the search button in the header and meny will show up @VahidAkhtar

Comment: https://snack.expo.io/HJ6U5CSAH

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to try this, [expo-snack](https://snack.expo.io/SkXfi180B) .

This is my below code for search.js ,

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet,TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';
import Menu from './menu';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome';

export default class Search extends React.Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state={
      isMenubarDisplayed: false,
    }
  }

 static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
  return {
    headerTitle: () => {
      return (
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={navigation.getParam('toggleMenu')}>
          <Icon name="search" size={20} color="#000" />
        </TouchableOpacity>
      );
    },
  };
};


toggleMenu = () => {
  this.setState({ isMenubarDisplayed: !this.state.isMenubarDisplayed})
}



  renderMenu = () => (
    <Menu />
  )

  componentDidMount(){
    this.props.navigation.setParams({
      toggleMenu: this.toggleMenu
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
      {this.state.isMenubarDisplayed?this.renderMenu():<View></View>}

      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
    padding: 8,
  },
});
```

Hope it helps. feel free for doubts.

Comment: Gaurav how to align this search button in middle of the  header? I have tried headerTitleStyle={ alignSelf:'center'}, its not working @GauravRoy

Comment: tar opore amio 1995.

Comment: yea, whatsapp a connect hote pari?

Answer (score 0):

This is all you need https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/header-buttons.html#header-interaction-with-its-screen-component

```
static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
  return {
    headerTitle: () => {
      return (
        <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center' }}>
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={navigation.getParam('toggleMenu')}>
            <Icon name="search" size={20} color="#000" /> 
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      );
    },
  };
};

componentDidMount() {
  this.props.navigation.setParams({ toggleMenu: this.toggleMenu });
}

toggleMenu = () => {
  this.setState({isMenubarDisplayed: true});
}
```

Comment: Getting the same error , this.setState not a function. @Tuan Luong

Comment: err:  this.setState is not a function. (In 'this.setState({
        isMenubarDisplayed: true
      })', 'this.setState' is undefined)

Comment: Did you try to restart metro bundle?

Comment: @TuanLuong you just needed to change the toggleMenu into a fat arrow function, i hope it will work after that

Comment: how to align this search button in middle of the header? I have tried headerTitleStyle={ alignSelf:'center'}, its not working

Comment: @SupriyaGorai. Just update the answer. Please check again!

Comment: Thanks Tuan Luong